# How can I update PyQt5 label text when a button is pressed?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to update a text over each event when the button "Url decode" is pressed:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(383, 156)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 231, 21))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 331, 51))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 90, 101, 16))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.update()
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Url decoder"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Url decode"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn)

    def btn(self):
        self.label.setText("Wait.") # I want this to be updated when event is running
        self.textEdit_2.clear()
        c = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        dados = {'u': c}
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        f = requests.post('http://checkshorturl.com/expand.php', data=dados, headers=headers)
        self.label.setText("Wait..") 
        a = re.search('<a href=\"(.+?)\"\starget', f.text)
        self.label.setText("Wait...")
        self.textEdit_2.setText(a[1])
        self.label.setText("Done")
        QApplication.processEvents()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I read something about `QApplication.processEvents()` but don't know how to use it, or where I put it on code. I want the word "Wait" to be updated through each event of the code when button is pressed.

Comment: There is no issue with your program actually it executes so fast that labels are overwritten fastly. you can use time.sleep(1) before the wait line and check

Comment: I really thought it would be fast that it wouldnt even update, but it take at least 2 seconds to answer, and dont even return the first "Wait."

Comment: Using `time.sleep` is a **terrible** suggestion, for two reasons: it doesn't take into account the time required by `requests.post`, and it also completely blocks the event loop (thus preventing user interaction and proper UI updating). You either use a QThread and a signal for the response, or, better, you use [QNetworkRequest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html).